# TLE trying to solve Fastflow on SPOJ using Dinic algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been trying to solve [Fastflow](https://www.spoj.com/problems/FASTFLOW/) on Spoj using Dinic algorithm, using C++, but I keep getting TLE. I'm wondering if there's any way to improve my code so it doesn't exceed time limit, or is the algorithm simply not fast enough for that task? I'm using BFS to find distance of each node from the source node and then DFS to see how much flow can be sent from the source to the sink.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Edge {
    int from, to, flow, capacity;
    Edge *reverse;
};

static vector<vector<Edge>> nodeEdges(5002, vector<Edge>());

int source, sink, nodes, level[5002];

void add(int u, int v, int c) {
    Edge e1{ u, v, 0, c };
    Edge e2{ v, u, 0, c };
    e1.reverse = &e2;
    e2.reverse = &e1;
    nodeEdges[u].push_back(e1);
    nodeEdges[v].push_back(e2);
}

bool bfs() {
    int s, t, u, v;
    memset(level, -1, sizeof(int)*(nodes+1));
    level[source] = 0;
    s = 0;
    t = 0;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(source);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeEdges[u].size(); i++) {
            v = nodeEdges[u][i].to;
            if (nodeEdges[u][i].flow < nodeEdges[u][i].capacity && level[v] == -1) {
                level[v] = level[u] + 1;
                q.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
    if (level[sink] == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

long long dfs(int u, int fl) {
    if (u == sink) return fl;
    int v;
    long long pushed;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeEdges[u].size(); i++) {
        v = nodeEdges[u][i].to;
        if (nodeEdges[u][i].flow < nodeEdges[u][i].capacity && level[v] == level[u] + 1) {
            pushed = dfs(v, min(nodeEdges[u][i].capacity - nodeEdges[u][i].flow, fl));
            if (pushed > 0) {
                nodeEdges[u][i].flow += pushed;
                nodeEdges[u][i].reverse->flow -= pushed;
                return pushed;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

long long solve() {
    long long ret = 0;
    long long flow;
    while (bfs()) {
        while (true) {
            flow = dfs(source, INT32_MAX);
            if (flow) {
                ret += flow;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n, m, a, b, c;
    cin >> n >> m;
    source = 1;
    sink = n;
    nodes = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        if (a != b) {
            add(a, b, c);
        }
    }
    cout << solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reverse` pointers for your added edges are all invalid, because they point to variables local to `add`.  They need to point to the nodes *after* they've been added to `nodeEdges[u]` (or `nodeEdges[v]`).

Comment: Are you sure about that? The answers seem to be correct either way, and when I tried to set the pointers after adding the edge to the vector memory usage would skyrocket and spoj would throw SIGABRT error instead of TLE.